# Is Cipher object reusable?

Tags: java, performance, encryption

Can I use the same `Cipher` object across multiple methods since the method arguments to `getInstance` and `init` do not change?

For example, assume multiple parts of the application use the `decrypt` method in a utility class. All the encrypted values passed are generated using the same key and algorithm. So, can I reuse the same `Cipher` object?

Is it really worth worrying about multiple creations of `Cipher` (which may result in creation of `KeySpec`, `SecretKey` objects)?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

You can re-use the cipher object but you have to initialize it every time by calling init() for every operation.

If you worry about recreating KeySpec, you should save it and use the same value in multiple init().

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to confirm, do you mean one init() invocation must for each doFinal() ?

Comment: As the Javadocs for doFinal() clearly state, "Upon finishing, this method resets this cipher object to the state it was in when previously initialized via a call to init. That is, the object is reset and available to encrypt or decrypt (depending on the operation mode that was specified in the call to init) more data."

Comment: GregS is correct. This answer is wrong. Unfortunately the stackoverflow wizards will not allow me to undo my erroneous upvote as it is now "locked in". Bad design choice wizards.

Comment: From Javadocs for init(): "Note that when a Cipher object is initialized, it loses all previously-acquired state. In other words, initializing a Cipher is equivalent to creating a new instance of that Cipher and initializing it."

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

As mentioned by the documentation:

> Upon finishing, this method resets this cipher object to the state it
>   was in when previously initialized via a call to init. That is, the
>   object is reset and available to encrypt or decrypt (depending on the
>   operation mode that was specified in the call to init) more data.

Comment: Worth noting that as the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal()) point out, a reset (re-initialization of cipher) might be needed in case any exception is thrown.

Answer (score -2):

Yes but... why? That is, there is almost zero overhead to the "new Cipher" implementation using whatever algorithm. There is more overhead to the "init()" call and that has to be redone anyway as follows:

```
  SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key,baseAlgorithm);
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
  IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey,ivSpec);
```

where:

- *key* is a byte array
- *baseAlgorithm* is a name like "AES" that is appropriate for key type
- *algorithm* is a name like "AES..."
- *iv* is the initialization vector (byte array)